# not able to login on magento 2 Windows 7 xampp

Tags: php, xml, magento2

I have install `Magento-2.1.9` on my local window system. Front website is working fine but when I try to login to admin I am not able to.

log say

> [2018-03-07 13:47:59] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3c470299521325284ed2f872fb317d47b and handles
>   default, adminhtml_auth_login: Please correct the XML data and try
>   again. [] []
>
> [2018-03-07 13:47:59] main.INFO: Cache file with merged
>   layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_331b80c99f1d265b3f83441bdff2abf85 and
>   handles admin-login: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

What can be the issue?

What I have tried

1. Enabled developer mode
2. clear all cache
3. reindex all files
4. deploy static content

I have checked both of the `xml` files `admin_login.xml` and `adminhtml_auth_login.xml` and they are valid.

Comment: your xml is screwed. fix it!

Comment: it's magento. it work on xmls which xml should I have checked. I already checked adminhtml xmls by netbean and they are fine

Comment: the layout, and the pages in question